# How to handle error within await Task.Run?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, error-handling

I try to call a method getOrders(id) with await Task.Run() within an async .net 5 API. If the method getOrders(id) produces an error, I want it to bubble up to the calling async Task GetIdAsny(int id). But i'm always stuck in the try/catch within getOrders and nothing bubbles up. I just don't get it. Thank you for your help.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetIdAsync(int id)
{
    try
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => getOrders(id));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //do something - never landing here
    }
}

private List<Order> getOrders(int id)
{
    try
    {
        List<Order> returnValue = new List<Order>();
        //doing something that produces an error
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //always stuck here
        throw new Exception("getOrders(" + id.ToString() + "):" + exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from your current issue, it's usually a bad idea to hide the original exception and only bubble up its message - better to pass it as the [inner exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Exception__ctor_System_String_System_Exception_) so that it retains stack trace, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thank you for your input, in the final version i'll do it like you recommend.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stuck in the try/catch"?